# Advantage of specifying 'localhost' over fully qualified domain name

Tags: php, mysql, server

I am running a web server and a MySQL server on same machine. Is there any advantage if I specify db host as 'localhost' instead of 'fully qualified domain name' in connection string in my PHP code?

Comment: the day you want to move the db to a different machine you just need to redirect the fully qualified name to that machine, for example.

Comment: There is no need to set FQDN if you can connect via localhost, to save DNS lookup time.

Comment: localhost is just an alias define in your host file wich associate this name to the 127.0.0.1 ip adress

Comment: @Raptor that's what my understand was, but was not able to search properly on net. Thanks.